# Model selection for multi-factor and hierarchical image data

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, unbalanced-classes

I've been trying to wrap my mind around the best way to test for differences within some data I have collected for a study I am finishing up. I have multiple questions that I just can't seem to find answers to that I feel good moving forward with.

I have two factors: treatment (radiation and control) and time after treatment (Baseline, 1, 24, and 48 hours). I'm a little fuzzy on how best to handle those four time levels, because the baseline level is only truly present in the control group (as it is before any treatment). I have considered randomly splitting my baseline samples into both treatments, but that feels hacky. Similarly, it was suggested that the Baseline is nearly identical to the 1 hour control group, but again, hacky (and presumptuous). I'd like to be able to test for the effect interaction, though, so I want the `treatment:time` factorial, if possible. **(1)  How do I test for interaction effect when a single level is not represented fully?**

I also have multiple levels of the nesting hierarchy, I think. This is where I start to get really fuzzy. Each animal in the study was given one treatment and measured at one time. 3 samples were taken from each animal, then from each sample, ~3 images were taken I do not have exactly 3 for images for each, but that was what I tried to do. In some cases, images were lost, in some cases, I took more. So now there is an imbalance at this level. **(2)  How do I deal with this imbalance appropriately while maintaining as much power as possible?**

Finally, each image 512x512 pixels. These images are highly heterogenous (i.e., there is structure within them), so I would like to consider the pixels of the images as data points, rather than the mean of the image as a data point. **(3):  How do I handle this deep-nesting?** Is it appropriate to simply nest pixels into regions which are nested into samples which are nested into animals?

FWIW, I am not well versed in statistics. My experience is simply a grad-level course that was taught in the engineering department (not the stats department). It was very much focused on the pragmatic and fundamental tests more than the theory...so in short, please take it easy on me!

**(Bonus) What is the best software or language to perform such a test in?** I've put off learning R, simply for lack of need, since I so rarely do complex tests. I know JMP moderately well, and I am proficient in Python. Can I do what I need in Python or JMP or is it worth learning R?